# ggplot2 change colours of flipped bars after producing plots

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, bar-chart

Using loops, I create a series of flipped barcharts, that look like the one made here. After creating them, I would like to give significantly different bars a different colour. therefore I need to change the colour of the bars after creating the plot. I have tried using `scale_fill_manual`, but this had no effect. here is how the data for 1 graph are structured, and my script

```
Station=rep("Station",5)
Slice=-1*(0:4)
mean.TD=c(344,1129,355,1349,674)
se.TD=c(114,438,121,390,14)
data115=data.frame(Station, Slice,mean.TD,se.TD)
data115


FC115=ggplot(data115, aes(x=Slice, y=mean.TD ))    +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +      
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean.TD-se.TD, ymax=mean.TD+se.TD), 
  width=3                                                                                           
  position=position_dodge(.9))+
theme_bw()+
ylab(expression("nematode densities (ind. 10cm"^-2*")"))  +      
xlab("Depth (cm)")+                                                   
coord_flip()     +                                             
scale_x_continuous(breaks = -4:0, labels=c("4-5","3-4","2-3","1-2","0-1"))           

FC115
```

Comment: How do you determine which bars are significantly different? Are there some grouping variable that shows that?

Comment: I don't determine this here. this is done through permanova. I only want to show which graphs I actually want to show. I have different stations, with different densities per layer. If densities in 1 station are different from the corresponding layer in the other station, I want to give them different colours.

Comment: One solution would be to have such variable that shows for which bar color should be changed. Then you could include it in aes() as fill=grouping variable.

Comment: I see a general problem here. Assume the following scenario: There are three bars, A, B, and C, with different heights. A is significantly different from C, but not from B. B is not significantly different from C. How would you colour these bars?

Comment: this is not entirely clear for me. I am producing several figures through a loop. As such, I am  producing different graphs, that all look the same. I need to change the color afterwards. I thought that aes() was used to start building a graph, not to change it afterwards.

Comment: @sven: A would be white, C would be black. B would be grey. Figure caption would be that black is significantly larger than white. grey is not different from any other bar.